# Vuex object state is correct but when trying to retrieve it says undefined

Tags: node.js, vuex

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ensMz.jpg

Hi, this is a debug picture of my store. I'm interested to retrieve the array found in:

**store -> state -> medicines -> all -> items**

As you can see, the array is populated with data (previously loaded through a mutation). When I try to print the array by using:

```
 console.log(this.$store.state.medicines.all.items)
```

I'm getting **undefined**.

```
data() {
    return {
      meds: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      medicines: state => state.medicines.all
    })
  },
  created() {
    this.getAllMeds()
    this.printMedicines()
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('medicines', {
      getAllMeds: 'getAll'
    }),
    printMedicines() {
      let medications = this.$store.state.medicines.all.items
      console.log(medications)
    }
  }
```

Edit: I have included the code snippet for further clarification.

Comment: Where are you trying to do the log from?

Comment: In a method inside **methods:** that I'm calling then in  **created()** after I call my **getAllMeds()** mutation method.

Comment: What happens in the `getAllMeds` mutation? Does it get data from a server?

Comment: Yes, it loads all the meds and changes the state of **medicines**. That part is working well, I've tested it via Vue dev tool to be sure. I will edit the post with some code snippets, maybe you can figure it out that way.

Comment: It sounds like the data is being returned asynchronously and that it might not have been loaded yet by the time you run the `console.log`.

Comment: @DelenaMalan You could be right, how shall I proceed in that case? I have included the code in the post now, so you can take a look.

Comment: I finally solved this by adding a watcher, it was indeed an async issue. Thanks, buddy :)